# Textfield value Issue in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm storing the name and email address of user in NSUserdefault which is coming from service and passing it to another VC but when i NSLog it, it shows me this,

```
<UITextField: 0x7f8d6548bcf0; frame = (16 366; 185 30); text = 'Shoaib Anwar'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000254ca0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800022b480>>
```

previously it was working fine but i don't know why it isn't working fine now.

Comment: how do you print this, show your `NSLog("")` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the **text** property of the **UITextField** then use `yourcurrentTextfieldname.text` on `NSLog`

```
NSLog(@"get text value  == %@",yourcurrentTextfieldname.text);
```

it will give the OP of

```
get text value  == Shoaib Anwar
```

but if you use like textfield property

```
NSLog(@"get text value  == %@",yourcurrentTextfieldname);
```

then you get the OP of whole property of the textfield.

```
 get text value == <UITextField: 0x7f8d6548bcf0; frame = (16 366; 185 30); text = 'Shoaib Anwar'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000254ca0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800022b480>>
```

Comment: Bro i'm running my app and getting Mach Linker error Linker command with exist code 1. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Resolved it and got it bro, thanks a lot. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - happy to hear this bro

Answer (score 0):

You should not print **TextField** object, it should `TextFiled text property`

```
NSLog(@"value  == %@",textField.text);
```